# iOS, How to load a .xib into another .xib?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xib, addsubview

I'm looking for a way to reuse content from one .xib file and load that into multiple other .xib files. Reason why is so i can reuse part of my design for all pages in my app. I know that in android programming, you can do this by writing include nameOfFile in your design .xml file.

I've tried the following:

Created a .xib file linked to a .h and .m file, they are all called ActionBarViewController .xib/.h/.m.

After that i set the backgroundcolor in my ActionBarViewController.m file.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIImage gbBlue];
```

My .h for ActionBarViewController looks like this:

```
@interface ActionBarViewController : UIViewController {

}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *actionBarView;

@end
```

Then i included my ActionBarViewController in my mainMenu.m (thats the .m file to the .xib i want load my ActionBar view into).

Now in my mainMenu.m's viewDidLoad i tried loading it like this.

```
ActionBarViewController *actionbarViewController = [[ActionBarViewController alloc] init];

[self.view addSubview:actionbarViewController.actionBarView];
[actionbarViewController release];
```

I've also tried:

```
ActionBarViewController *obj=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ActionBarViewController" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];

obj.actionBarView.frame=CGRectMake(70, 160, 180, 80);

[self.view addSubview:obj.actionBarView];
[obj release];
```

But its not working, so am i missing something? Or is this not even possible in iOS programming?

Comment: Anyone able to help me any further with this?

Comment: still stuck, anyone out there plz help!

Answer (score 1):

1. Simple you have to just create object of second xib and add in main
   view,like below:

   ```
   SecondXib obj=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SecondXib" owner:self
   options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];

   obj.frame=CGRectMake(70, 160, 180, 80);

   [self.view addsubview:obj];
   ```

Note : You have to use **secondXib** as **UIView**

Comment: 2 questions. what is the loadNibNamed used for? and what is the obj.frame=CGRectMake used for?

Comment: loadNibNamaed for that particular xib view that you want to add and frame for in which position you want to add that particular xib view.

Comment: I get 2 errors. 1. interface type cannt be statically allocated. 2. property "frame" not found on object of type "ActionBarViewController*"

Comment: what is the type of your "ActionBarViewController" it must be UIView i already write it in note.

Comment: @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *actionBarView; thats my pointer to the view. So it seems like it is a UIView

Comment: your "actionBatrViewController" type must be UIView @interface ActionBarViewController:UIView

Comment: is it my property actionBarView or the class ActionBarViewController i need to use as SecondXib?

Comment: you can use 2nd xib as a UIView not as UIViewController.

Comment: so in my ActionBarViewController.h i need to change @interface ActionBarViewController : UIViewController. to UIView and not UIViewController?

Comment: If i change my ActionBarViewController from a UIViewController to UIView I'm no longer able to set the backgroundcolor in my ActionbarViewController.m

Comment: Plz take a look on my updated question. I've tried to use this solution, but I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a mainmenu's `xib`, and you are trying to load in a specific `view` defined in that `xib`. lets name it as `containerView`. Link that `containerView` with your main .m file `init` your `ActionBarView` in the `viewDidLoad`. Use some class method in `ActionBarView` to load the `nib` file and return the results. Than add that as a `subview` in your `containerView`.

```
//viewDidLoad
    ActionBarView *actionBar = [ActionBarView getInstance];
    [containerView addSubview:actionBar]

//Class method getInstance in ActionBarViewController
    ActionBarView *actionBar = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                          loadNibNamed:@"ActionBarViewController" 
                                          owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
    if ([actionBar isKindOfClass:[ActionBarView class]])
        return actionBar;
    else
        return nil;
```

`ActionBarView` is a `UIView`

Comment: I'm, trying to load a view from another separat .xib file, so that view can be used in multiple other .xib files

Comment: so thats what i said...whereever you want to use that xib file (ActionBar in your case)
Make a container view for view for it in your mainMenu xib
and in viewDidLoad of mainMenu create an instance of ActionBar. For instantiating, you can use a class method like shown above.

Than add the actionBar instance in your container in the viewDidLoad method of mainMenu

Comment: And you dont actually need another view controller like you made an ActionBarViewController. If you just want to reuse it in another xib's, then just make it a UIView. It will be reusable again and again. You will just need to add your action bar **UIView** in some container in the main xib.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating controller by below way:

```
ActionBarViewController *actionbarViewController = [[ActionBarViewController alloc] init];
```

This is not proper if you want to init the controller via xib. Correct way is:

```
ActionBarViewController *actionbarViewController = [[ActionBarViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ActionBarViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: No errors found, but still gets nothing cant see the backgroundcolor of the view or the image i put onto my ActionbarViewController:(